# Why am I seeing error 1004 when range copying?

Tags: excel, vba

Why am I seeing error 1004 here?

```
Set s1= workbooks("xxx.xlsx").worksheets("abc")
S1.range("A1", Range("A1").end(xldown)).copy
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error? And what is the code before and after these lines? Don't re-type your code here, use cope-paste to avoid typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put Name of Workbook and Sheet in quotes

```
Set s1 = workbooks("xxx.xlz").worksheets("abc")
```

Change the second line to

```
s1.Range("A1", s1.Range("A1").end(xldown)).copy
```

Comment: Thanks. The quotes are actually missed out by me when I was describing the problem. So the issue should be something else instead